# Emacs, how to get directory of current buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs there is buffer-file-name that gives the full path to a file. But is there a way to get only the directory of the file loaded in the current buffer?

Comment: `default-directory` variable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `default-directory` variable.

> Documentation:
>   Name of default directory of current buffer.  Should end with slash.
>   To interactively change the default directory, use command `cd'.

Note that `expand-file-name` will use `default-directory` by default, so sometimes
you don't even need to mention it.

Answer (score 52):

Sometimes `default-directory` for the current buffer may be set to something other than the current directory of the file the buffer is currently visiting, in which case the solution above wouldn't give what the asker was looking for.

In such cases, you can use the `file-name-directory` method, like so: `(file-name-directory buffer-file-name)`

Here is a link to the docs:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html

Comment: Yes, abo-abo's answer addresses the question in the *title*, but Sandy's answer is what I'd recommend if you're specifically dealing with `buffer-file-name` (although the chances of it ever making a difference are slim).

Comment: `buffer-file-name` is a function, so this should be `(file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))`.

Comment: Actually, according to the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html), `buffer-file-name` is both a function and a buffer-local variable, so both `(file-name-directory buffer-file-name)` and `(file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))` should work.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. :)

Comment: I'm curious now if there is any reason to prefer one over the other....

Comment: `buffer-file-name` can be `nil`, e.g. on the `*scratch*` buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command **`M-x pwd`** to see the value of `default-directory` in the current buffer.

Each buffer has a default directory, stored in the buffer-local variable `default-directory`. Whenever Emacs reads a file name using the minibuffer, it usually inserts the default directory into the minibuffer as the initial contents. When you visit a file, Emacs sets `default-directory` in the visiting buffer to the directory of its file.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Names.html